# Winsock: DisconnectEx with IO Completion port

Tags: sockets, winsock, winsock2, io-completion-ports

NB: the OP confirms in the comment thread that the problem was due to a typo, not shown in the posted code.

---

I was expecting to get a notification using GetQueuedCompletionStatus after scheduling an overlapped disconnect with DisconnectEx. I never get one - is this by design? If I specify a manual reset event in the OVERLAPPED structure this is signalled to indicate that the disconnect is complete, but GetQueuedCompletionStatus never returns.

My call to DisconnectEx looks a bit like this (note that context has an operator LPOVERLAPPED and ol is the first element in the structure):

```
context.ol.hEvent = hEvent;
BOOL result = DisconnectEx(context.socket, context, TF_REUSE_SOCKET, 0);
if (result)
{
    // we completed synchronously:
    ProcessCompletion(0, context, 0);
}
else
{
    int error = WSAGetLastError();
    if (error != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
    {
        throw ServerSocketException("DisconnectEx failed");
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
    std::cout << "disconnected - event signalled\n";
}
```

I added the WaitForSingleObject when I found that GetQueuedCompletionStatus didn't return. What is the correct way to detect DisconnectEx completing? I want to use the socket again in a call to AcceptEx.

Comment: So, if you use WaitForSingleObject it works as expected, but if you use GetQueuedCompletionStatus it doesn't?  That's odd - I'm fairly sure GetQueuedCompletionStatus calls WaitForSingleObject internally.  Can you show the version of the code that doesn't work as well as the one that does?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, you are right. It works when calling WaitForSingleObject but not GetQueuedCompletionStatus. However, I don't think GetQueuedCompletionStatus calls WaitForSingleObject internally, otherwise you would run into trouble if you wanted to wait on more than 64 sockets (and you definitely want to do this if you are developing a high-capacity server).

Comment: @AdrianS - it's a queue - you only need to wait on one semaphore, no matter how many IO completion packets get queued to it from kernel threadpools.

Comment: @MartinJames - however, WaitForSingleObject waits on a specific single handle (e.g. an event handle). Now supposing I disconnect 100 sockets - how do I wait for all of those disconnects to complete?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of GetOverlappedResult; OK, so you're using I/O completion ports.  The first things to double-check are that the socket handle really is associated with the completion port and that there isn't any other asynchronous I/O already using that particular OVERLAPPED structure.  Are you able to post a complete working sample demonstrating the issue?

Comment: The table in [Receiving Completion Indications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740115(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests that winsock only supports I/O completion ports if hEvent is set to NULL; did you try this?

Comment: @AdrianS - wait on a semaphore.  The kernel thread/s push on 100 completions and signal the semaphore 100 times.  Your user threads deque 100 completions and the semaphore is empty again, so they block.  You only need the concurrent queue and the one semaphore.

Comment: @MartinJames: yes, but the problem is (or appears to be) that the semaphore in question isn't actually getting signaled.  At this point I don't think we can make progress without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MartinJames: I am not sure what you are getting at. I already said that I am waiting using GetQueuedCompletionStatus.

Comment: Show more code. I need to see how you set up your socket and the overlapped structure you're using. Given the wait on an event I assume you're not using IOCP and so any comments about GetQueuedCompletionStatus are bogus. For a given socket handle either wait on an event for I/O operations OR associate with an IOCP, not both.

Comment: @LenHolgate thanks for your comment. I added the wait on event in frustration just to see if it would be signalled - it was never my intention to use events. In the end I found out that due to a typo, the socket was not correctly associated with the port.

Comment: You should add an answer stating that this is due to a typo, and set that answer as accepted so that people don't have to read this whole thread of comments to get to the result.

Answer (score 0):

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397604/winsock-disconnectex-with-io-completion-port#comment38152213_24397604) that this was because of a typo on the OP's part.

(Posting an answer so other people don't have to read the comment thread...)

Comment: Shouldn't the question instead be closed as "caused by a simple typographical error" ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: no idea; feel free to. I don't care either way.